# Add quotes for each field if it is not enclosed with quotes using sed/awk/perl

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I want to add quotes for each field if the field values is not enclosed with quotes.

Scenario 1 :
Below is my input

```
eno;ename;address;gender
1;AaA;"mnop qrstzyx";M
2;bB;"abc";F
3;cC;"adef;mnp";ars
4;mnp;ade;M
```

Expected output

```
"eno";"ename";"address";"gender"
"1";"AaA";"mnop qrstzyx";"M"
"2";"bB";"abc";"F"
"3";"cC";"adef;mnp";"ars"
"4";"mnp";"ade";"M"
```

Options which i tried

```
sed 's/[^;]*/"&"/g'
```

Scenario 2 :
Below is my input

```
eno;ename;address;gender
1;AaA;"mnop 
qrst
zyx";M
2;bB;"abc";F
3;cC;"adef;
mnp";ars
4;mnp;ade;M
```

Expected output

```
"eno";"ename";"address";"gender"
"1";"AaA";"mnop qrstzyx";"M"
"2";"bB";"abc";"F"
"3";"cC";"adef;mnp";"ars"
"4";"mnp";"ade";"M"
```

Comment: Try `perl -pe 's/(?<![^;])".*?"(?![^;])(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([^;"\r\n]+)/"$1"/g' file`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, It works fine. Can you explain bit more what does the above command does

Comment: It matches all quoted fields and omits these matches, and then grabs all chunks of 1+ chars other than `"`, `;` and CR/LFs, and wraps them with `"`s.

Comment: Thank you wiktor, I added scenario 2 in the same question

Comment: Any suggestions for scenario 2

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001.

Answer (score 3):

Use `FPAT` with `gnu awk` to handle CSV files

```
awk -v FPAT='([^;]*)|("[^"]+")' -v OFS=";" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i!~/^\"/) $i="\""$i"\""}} 1' file
"eno";"ename";"address";"gender"
"1";"AaA";"mnop qrstzyx";"M"
"2";"bB";"abc";"F"
"3";"cC";"adef;mnp";"ars"
"4";"mnp";"ade";"M"
```

Comment: for Scenario 1 Quotes are adding at beginning and ending not for each field

Comment: @user1485267 from your request `"1";"AaA";"mnop qrstzyx";"M"`  do you like this insted? `"1;AaA;"mnop qrstzyx";M"`

Comment: Yes i need it like this "1";"AaA";"mnop qrstzyx";"M"

Comment: @user1485267 and my answer is not what you describe???  My answer `"1";"AaA";"mnop qrstzyx";"M"`,  your request `"1";"AaA";"mnop qrstzyx";"M"`

Comment: not sure why it doesn't worked to me.. Sorry it might be version issue

Comment: @EdMorton Do you mean change  `FPAT="([^;]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"` to  `FPAT="([^;]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")"`?

Answer (score 2):

Perl one liner using the useful [Text::AutoCSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::AutoCSV) module:

```
perl -MText::AutoCSV -e 'Text::AutoCSV->new(in_file=>"input.txt",
    out_file=>"output.txt",
    sep_char=>";",
    out_always_quote=>1)->write()'
```

And to squash newlines in fields:

```
perl -MText::AutoCSV -e 'Text::AutoCSV->new(in_file=>"input.txt",
    out_file=>"output.txt",
    sep_char=>";",
    out_always_quote=>1,
    read_post_update_hr=>sub{
        while(my ($k,$v) = each %{$_[0]}){
            ${$_[0]}{$k}=$v=~s/\n//gr
        } })->write()'
```

will output

```
"eno";"ename";"address";"gender"
"1";"AaA";"mnop qrstzyx";"M"
"2";"bB";"abc";"F"
"3";"cC";"adef;mnp";"ars"
"4";"mnp";"ade";"M"
```

If you have non-trivial CSV-like data like yours, it's always better to use an actual CSV parser instead of trying to hack around with regular expressions trying to get something to work.

Comment: Is there any way outfile can be placed directly to hadoop file system instead of local file system without landing to intermediate area by using your command

Comment: @user1485267 Not a clue; I am completely ignorant of hadoop.

Comment: Ok, No issues. Can we keep the output of data in memory and process output with redirection. for example perl 'command' > output.txt

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^";]*"[^"]*)*"[^";]*);/\1\n/;ta;s/"//g;s/[^;]*/"&"/g;y/\n/;/' file
```

Change the `;`'s within double quoted strings to something else (`\n`). Remove double quotes from all fields. Surround all characters which are not delimiters (`;`) by double quotes. Finally replace newlines by `;`'s.

The second example needs newlines removed from within double quoted strings. A separate solution for this is:

```
sed -Ez ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^"\n]*"[^"]*)*"[^"\n]*)\n/\1/;ta' file
```

Or, for older seds:

```
sed -r '1h;1!H;$!d;x;:a;s/^([^"]*("[^"\n]*"[^"]*)*"[^"\n]*)\n/\1/;ta' file
```

The overall solution is a combination of the above, where the file is first treated by the second solution which is piped into the first solution e.g.

```
sed -Ez ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^"\n]*"[^"]*)*"[^"\n]*)\n/\1/;ta' file |
sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^";]*"[^"]*)*"[^";]*);/\1\n/;ta;s/"//g;s/[^;]*/"&"/g;y/\n/;/'
```

Comment: it didnt work with the final solution.. it is adding quotes without appending to previous line.. if my filename is input.csv

Comment: @user1485267 I do not understand your comment. For both scenario 1 and 2 I get the same result.

Comment: when i run sed -Ez ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^"\n]*"[^"]*)*"[^"\n]*)\n/\1/;ta' input.csv |
sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^";]*"[^"]*)*"[^";]*);/\1\n/;ta;s/"//g;s/[^;]*/"&"/g;y/\n/;/' like this i am getting issues syntax wrong

Comment: Thank u potong.. is there any way which i can run first command and save the result in one file and from that file i want to do second sed after pipe

Comment: @user1485267 you can use a tee command e.g. `command1 inputFile | tee saveFile1 | command2  >saveFile2`

Comment: It is only because of -Ez script causing me the issue when i ran your command with -Ez it gives me invalid option --z. Can you suggest me what will be  the other way to achive it without 'z' parameter second command it doesn't work

Comment: I tried like below way by removing z in your command it didn't worked.sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^"\n]*"[^"]*)*"[^"\n]*)\n/\1/;ta' file |
sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^";]*"[^"]*)*"[^";]*);/\1\n/;ta;s/"//g;s/[^;]*/"&"/g;y/\n/;/'

Comment: My sed version is GNU Sed 4.2.1

Comment: It throws an issue like below for the older sed's sed: -e expression #1, char 58: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS.  Command : sed '1h;1!H;$!d;x;:a;s/^([^"]*("[^"\n]*"[^"]*)*"[^"\n]*)\n/\1/;ta' file

Comment: Thank you it worked fine with adding extra -r in your last modified command i.e sed -r '1h;1!H;$!d;x;:a;s/^([^"]*("[^"\n]*"[^"]*)*"[^"\n]*)\n/\1/;ta' file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199348/discussion-between-user1485267-and-potong).

Comment: when the filesize is big the command gets hanged around 150MB file I am trying to replace it.

Comment: Are there any suggestions which can be provided

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a simple `awk` (standard Linux `gawk`) script that update each line and print it

```
awk '{
     gsub(/;/, "\";\""); # input line substitute all ; with ";"
     print "\"" $0 "\""; # print input line wrapped with "
}' input.txt
```

or one liner

```
awk '{gsub(/;/, "\";\"");print "\"" $0 "\"";}' input.txt
```

Comment: That would turn `a;"b;c"` into `"a";""b";"c""` instead of the desired `"a";"b;c"`.